# I'm launching a .bat file through java,i want read that .bat command prompt data ,how?

Tags: java

I am launched a .bat file through java,when it launches the output will be generated on the command prompt console,we need to read that lines ,please help it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Runtime` class. The following code will do what you describe:

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();  // get instance of Runtime object
Process process = runtime.exec("batch command here");  // executes the command and create a Process object to represent it
process.getOutputStream() ...  // to read from the output of the program
process.getErrorStream() ...  // to read from the error stream of of the program
```